# Connection between same nodes of different graph in python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I want to create graph between authors of different research papers.
I am able to create a graph between all authors of same paper. But I am unable to connect it with other graph .

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
authors= {0:{'a1':'Brian Vickery',
             'a2':'Fatma Özcan',
              'a3':'George Lapis',
              'a4':'Guy M. Lohman',
              'a5':'Hamid Pirahesh',
              'a6':'Jim Kleewein',
              'a7':'Kevin S. Beyer',
              'a8':'Normen Seemann',
              'a9':'Robert Lyle',
              'a10':'Roberta Cochrane',
              'a11':'Tuong C. Truong',
              'a12':'Vanja Josifovski'},
          1:{ 'a1':'Robert Lyle',
              'a2':'Bingsheng He',
              'a3':'Mian Lu',
              'a4':'Ke Yang',
              'a5':'Naga K. Govindaraju',
              'a6':'Qiong Luo',
              'a7':'Pedro V. Sander'}}
```

I separate the values of key 0, and create graph on it, similarly separating the value of key 1 I can create a graph on its values. But I am unable to connect nodes of both graph

```
keys = list(authors .keys())

tups = list(zip(keys, keys[1:]+keys[0:1]))
g = nx.Graph()
for a,b in tups:
    g.add_edge(authors[a], authors[b])

nx.draw(g)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Following both of graph has node name as Robert Lyle. My question is that how can I connect both of these nodes
[image: graph having values of key 0]

[image: graph having values of key 1]

Comment: What does `nx` do ?

Comment: @ma3oun pardon please, I forget to mention it , I am making graph using networkx library of python alias as nx

Comment: Is there a reason you've connected an author only to two adjacent authors?  Typically we think of all authors on a paper as forming a clique in which everyone is connected to everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create two graphs. Add the edges between all the Authors of both the groups (or papers) in the same graph. This will ensure that if same author is part of multiple papers, the network will be connected. If two research papers have completely different authors, then it will yield disjointed graphs.

Try the following:

- Each node in the graph should represent an author (irrespective of
  which group (or research paper category) he/she belongs to.
- Edges between the authors can represent the group (or research paper)
  based on which they are connected.

Comment: my data is in the form of dictionary of dictionary.. in which data structure, I have to convert first, before passing it to netowrkx library

Comment: Can you post your complete code which you are using to generate and display the graph in your question?

Comment: its already complete code. I am justing calling key as authors=authors[0], and then run code

Answer (score 0):

Usually every author is connected to every other other on the paper:

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx

authorlist = [list(paperauthors.values()) for papername, paperauthors in author.items()]

g = nx.Graph()
edgelist = [a1, a2 for paperauthors in authorlist for a1, a2 in itertools.combinations(paperauthors, 2)]
g.add_edges_from(edgelist)
```